# Haskell Failed to load interface for module

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, cabal

Hello i am trying to use a module inside another module but it seems it just won't work.I tried updating the cabal file,stack,i reinstalled the platform,ghc and everything and it just won't let it import modules.I tried adding in the cabal file both other-modules and home-modules section ..to no effect.What could be the problem?

Modules:

```
module Test where


    test::IO()
    test=do
        elem<-getLine
        print elem


module Main where

import Test

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "hello world"
```

Cabal-build renders this error:

$ cabal build

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring console-0.1.0.0...
Warning: To use the 'default-language' field the package needs to specify at
least 'cabal-version: >= 1.10'.
Preprocessing executable 'console' for console-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'console' for console-0.1.0.0..

<no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: Test

<no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: Test
```

When i build with Stack i get this error:

```
C:\<path>\Main.hs:4:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for `Test'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
H>>= :module + *Main
```

Cabal file:

```
 name:                console
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:
-- description:
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/console#readme
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Bercovici Adrian Simon
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2018 Bercovici Adrian Simon
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.2
extra-source-files:  README.md


Executable console
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010

  build-depends:       base                  >= 4.7    && < 5
  other-modules:       Test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `other-modules:` directive must go inside the `Executable console` stanza.

Comment: N.B. [The docs](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#editing-the-cabal-file)

Comment: I have tried with this solution too but still the same problem.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Could not reproduce. Show us the version of `console.cabal` that you believe has my proposed fix included but still produces those messages.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian You changed two things: you removed your `build-depends:` line (why??) and you moved the `other-modules:` line. Don't do that. Leave the `build-depends:` line as it was, and *only* move `other-modules` into the `Executable console` stanza.

Comment: Ok so this should do it?Because if yes it does not.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Works for me. What is the exact error you are getting now? What does `tree` say?

Comment: Ok so now it is funny.When running cabal build it does build.When i am running stack ghci --test --no-load --no-build --main-is TARGET --ghci-options -fprint-evld-with-show in <project path> i get : Failed to load interface for `Test'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
H>>= :module + *Main
<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module `Main'
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.

Comment: Ok so i now i tried Stack -build and Stack run and it works.But i have to do it manually from the console whereas with VS-Code i was just pressing F5

Comment: When pressing "F5" this command is executed which still gives me the dreaded error  : stack ghci --test --no-load --no-build --main-is TARGET --ghci-options -fprint-evld-with-show in C:\Users\<path>

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian That sounds like a completely separate question to me. Feel free to open up a fresh post with further details!

Comment: I will do that, thank you for helping me,and for your patience!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166487/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-daniel-wagner).